# subprocess.Popen produces error while, commands run smoothly in command line (ERROR: find: paths must precedeexpression)

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu, subprocess

I am trying to incorporate a few commands into a python script that I typically would use in a command line (Ubuntu 14.04) to deal with files.

I tried following the example on the [subprocess help page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), but it hits me with the following error message:

```
find: paths must precede expression: |
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

The reason, I am a little stumped is that it excutes properly, if I type it directly in the console. I am suspecting there is something wrong how the arguments are parsed, but imo the printed out results for `argv1` and `argv2` to looked like expected (based on the example).

```
import subprocess, shlex



cmd1 = "find . -name *.tgz | xargs -i pigz -dv {}"
cmd2 = "find . -name *.tar | xargs -i tar -xfv {} -C decompressed --wildcards '*B5.TIF' '*B6.TIF' '*B8.TIF' "

args1 = shlex.split(cmd1)
args2 = shlex.split(cmd2)

print args1
print args2 

subprocess.call(args1)
subprocess.call(args2)
```

I tried `subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.Popen()` with the same results. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're running into this error because of the pipes in your commands.

You'll want to do something like this instead (this is just for cmd1):

```
cmd1=`find . -name *.tgz | xargs -i pigz -dv {}`
# should instead be
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["find", ".", "-name", "*.tgz"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["xargs", "-i", "pigz", "-dv", "{}"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

For more details read the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline).

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.Popen(args1,shell=True)` or `subprocess.call(args1,shell=True)`  with `shell=True` works fine on Ubuntu 14.04 for me.

*Warning Executing shell commands that incorporate unsanitized input from an untrusted source makes a program vulnerable to shell injection, a serious security flaw which can result in arbitrary command execution. For this reason, the use of shell=True is strongly discouraged in cases **where the command string is constructed from external input**:*

Comment: Thanks! You were right, the `shell=True` worked. Can you elaborate a little bit, when it is necessary? Lots of posts on here and the documentation itself cautions the use of `shell=True`

Comment: @Phill  I added the important part about using shell=True, if you were taking input from an external source then it would be dangerous, in your case just running commands you should not have to worry.

Comment: Actually, I got too excited, it executed... but it negated the pipe. The output pretty much resembled the `find` command's output, but not the output after it went through the next step.